# Does Authentication type on Local SQL Server 2008 R2 DB matter once uploaded to webhost

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, web-hosting

I currently have my SQL server database on my local PC which I have connected to a website that I am developing. At the moment I am using Windows Authentication to log in to my database. My question is, Once I upload this database to a web host like winHost.com, Does the authentication type matter at all that is on my local machine as long as I change the path in my website's code to point to the web host database?

I Have never uploaded a database to a web host so this is a question that came about and I want to avoid any issues before they actually happen if possible. I'm thinking that it may sort of "reset" the database password to whatever I enter in the web host's settings but I'm looking for some reinforcing thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the authentication type does matter. The way windows authentication mode works means that the server hosting your website would need to be aware of your active directory account in order to validate your login.

Here are some steps in order to host SQL Server locally and access it from your website being hosted somewhere else:

- You will need a static IP address in order to point your website back to your local SQL Server. Some ISPs offer a static IP address for an additional nominal fee. My last ISP charged $5/month and my current ISP provides one for free. That's why I switched ;)
- I recommend changing the default port from 1433 to something else and of course allowing access to the port through your firewall. Also, Google to find out other ways to protect your computer and SQL Server from hackers since you will be exposing your computer on the internet. Personally, I prefer limiting the attack surface to the smallest surface possible.
- Set SQL Server to run in mixed authentication mode both Windows Authentication and SQL Server login. Of course you will to supply a username/password. In your application change your database connection string to something like Server=myServerIPAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;. You can find more SQL Server connection strings on  [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)
- On SQL Server create a login with access to your database and limit the permissions as much as possible to make your application work. This is to keep the attack surface small.
- Open SQL Server Configuration Manager and under SQL Server Network Configuration find your SQL Server instance. In the right pane double click 'TCP/IP' and on the protocol tab select 'Enabled'. Under the 'IP Addresses' tab clear out the values in 'TCP Dynamic Ports' and 'TCP Port' under all IP addresses **EXCEPT** IPAll. Under IPAll enter in your port number from the step above. restart your SQL Server services.

Comment: So if i just upload the database to the web host and don't run the database from my local machine I wouldn't have to worry about changing ports and Windows Authentication would I?

Comment: No, in that scenario you would not have to worry about windows authentication or ports, but your web hosting company will set up your SQL Server. Typically your web hosting company will set up your database on their server and give you admin rights. Then you will have to upload your tables, procs, etc. In your application you will have to use the database connection string they provide to point to your database.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answers they have been very helpful and will let me know what to look forward to when I start the process.